# files not staged after git stash pop

Tags: git

I made some changes to code I'm tracking using git. Those changes were staged (added). Then I stashed them using `git stash`. Then I unstashed them using `git stash pop`. At that point the changes were no longer staged. Is this the expected behavior? If so, is it described in git docs?

Comment: I personally prefer `git stash apply` over `pop` as this allows me to try again if something went wrong.

Comment: Looking at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash pop seems to just apply the changes to the working tree.

Comment: I am seeing seemingly inconsistent behavior - starting with all changes staged, then stashed, then (switch branches, do stuff, switch back), then pop -- some files (ones that were newly added) are staged, and others (those that were deleted or modified) are not staged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell git to *try* to restore the index state

```
git stash pop --index
```

At first glance, it's confusing, and might even seem like a bug, that this isn't the default behavior; especially if you've looked closely enough to know that internally a stash *does* preserve knowledge of what was staged vs. what was in the working tree when the stash was created.  But it is what's documented (see the `git stash` docs under `pop`).

The problem, though, is that if there are conflicts when applying the stash, then the index is needed for conflict resolution... so the `--index` operation then has to fail.  So, for better or worse, the default behavior is to do an operation that will more certainly work (even if it has to leave you in a "resolve conflicts" state).

Comment: Very helpful. However, i don't see it documented with git stash as you mention. Are you referring perhaps to other documentation somewhere?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash ; under `pop` - "Remove a single stashed state from the stash list and apply it *on top of the current working tree state*" ... "If the --index option is used, then *tries to reinstate not only the working tree’s changes, but also the index’s ones*."